# Snowflake udf logic

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have created some SQL UDF there return a table which work as it should.

Now I would like to add some logic so based on the input parameters of the udf, different queries should be used e.g:

```
if input_parameter = A then
    SELECT * FROM table where blabla
if input_parameter = B then
    SELECT * FROM table_someting where blabla
```

Is that possible (with sql or python in snowflake)? and then still able to call it like:

```
select * from table(myfunction("A"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UDTF logic could be written as mutually exclusive `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab1 
WHERE blabla
  AND INPUT_PARAMETER = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table_something
WHERE blabla
  AND INPUT_PARAMETER = 'B'
```